# "ExceptionMessage":"Unknown error (0x80005000)" Active Directory (AD)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

Ok my problem is that i have made a web-application, where it access AD to check if your part of a specific group. It works fine in visual studio(with the IIS express server), but when i deploy it to a real IIS server i get this error(when CredentialsController.Get() is called):

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unknown error (0x80005000)","ExceptionType":"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException","StackTrace":"   
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()\r\n  
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()\r\n   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)\r\n   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)\r\n   
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)\r\n   
at Forsikringsapp.Core.Services.ADLookupService.IsInGroup(PrincipalContext ctx, String user, String group)\r\n   
at Forsikringsapp.Web.Controllers.CredentialsController.Get()\r\n
```

So i'm guessing i need to configure something on the IIS-server, just can't find out what.

Comment: Check the event viewer, it might have a better message. I would guess that it is your app pool user not having rights to query AD.

Comment: It's likely to be the user it's connecting to AD as. The App Pool is likely to be AppPoolIdentity, which is Anonymous user. Try changing the app pool identity to NetworkService & see if that works